# Bad Request Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'. Using Python, sqlite, flask, API

Tags: python, html, api, sqlite, pyscript

Bad Request
Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'. is returned when trying to POST and PUT data into database using flast API.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/records/<objectid>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def api_get_object(objectid):
    return jsonify(getobjects(objectid))

@app.route('/api/add-object/<name>/<type>',  methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def api_add_object(name, type):
    name = request.get_json()
    type = request.get_json()
    return jsonify(insertVaribleIntoTable(name, type))
```

I assume there is something wrong with the methods... Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The error message complains about how you are making the request (you have to instruct `curl` or whatever you are using to send an appropriate `Content-Type` header), otherwise the server will not treat the request body as JSON.

Comment: This does not help